# Understanding the Yennie-Frautschi-Suura (YFS) Infrared Exponentiation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, research-level, infrared-radiation

I am trying to understand an alternative derivation of the Yennie-Frautschi-Suura (YFS) virtual photon exponentiation, given by Grammer and Yennie, in their paper "Improved treatment of the infrared-divergence problem in QED" (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.8.4332). After providing an overview, I believe anyone with a some experience in QFT (and in particular in QED) will be able to see what steps I need to take in order to derive the desired result.

The result I am trying to understand is described in Section 2-B of the paper. The authors are trying to attach a virtual $K$-photon into a Feynman diagram with $n$ photons already attached on it. The $n$ photons can be either virtual or real. The $K$-photon is the photon that corresponds to the Feynman propagator
$$\frac{-i}{l^2+i\epsilon}K^{\mu\nu}=\frac{-i}{l^2+i\epsilon}l^{\mu}l^{\nu}b$$
(I am using P&S notation and definitions) which occurs after decomposing the propagator into $K$- photons and $G$- photons
$$\frac{-ig^{\mu\nu}}{l^2+i\epsilon}=\frac{-i}{l^2+i\epsilon}K^{\mu\nu}+\frac{-i}{l^2+i\epsilon}G^{\mu\nu}$$
and $b$ depends on the momenta carried by the fermions attached on the $K$- propagator ($p_f$ and $p_i$) and the momentum carried by the additional (virtual) $K$-photon ($l_j$).
$$b^{(j)}(p_f,p_i)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{(2p_f-l_j)\cdot(2p_i-l_j)}{(l^2_j-2l_j\cdot p_f)(l^2_j-2l_j\cdot p_i)}, & p_f\ne p_i\\
    \frac{1}{2}\Big[\frac{(2p_f-l_j)\cdot(2p_i-l_j)}{(l^2_j-2l_j\cdot p_f)(l^2_j-2l_j\cdot p_i)}+(l_j\leftrightarrow-l_j)\Big], & p_f=p_i
  \end{cases}$$

Let us just focus in the case in which $n=1$. Let us assume that there exists the simplest of graphs, in which an electron with momentum $p$ is the incoming particle interactin in some way (assume some external potential) with a source and then it turns into the outgoing particle, with momentum $p'$. Let us also assume that the electron emits one photon before interacting with the source (and hence $n=1$). The amplitude before adding the additional $K$- photon is given by
$$\bar{u}(p')\Gamma\frac{i}{\not{p}_1-m}\not{\epsilon}^*_1u(p)$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the interaction with the source, $\epsilon_1^*$ is the polarization vector for the outgoing photon (I have ommitted the -ie coming from the photon emission vertex), and $p_1$ is the momentum carried by the electron after having emitted the photon.

Now we add one additional $K$- photon propagator. From what I understand there are three cases:

1. $K$- photon being emitted and reabsorbed by the initial (real) electron:
   $$-\frac{2i\alpha}{(2\pi)^3}\bar{u}(p')\Gamma\int\frac{d^4l}{l^2}b^{(2)}(p,p)
   \frac{i}{\not{p}_1-m}\not{\epsilon}^*_1
   \frac{i}{\not{p}-m}\not{l}\frac{(-i)}{\not{p}-\not{l}-m}\not{l}
   u(p)$$
2. $K$- photon being emitted by the initial (real) electron and reabsorbed by the virtual one:
   $$-\frac{2i\alpha}{(2\pi)^3}\bar{u}(p')\Gamma\int\frac{d^4l}{l^2}b^{(2)}(p,p)
   \frac{i}{\not{p}_1-m}\not{l}\frac{1}{\not{p}_1-\not{l}-m}
   \not{\epsilon}^*_1
   \frac{1}{\not{p}-\not{l}-m}\not{l}u(p)$$
3. $K$- photon being emitted and reabsorbed by the virtual electron:
   $$-\frac{2i\alpha}{(2\pi)^3}\bar{u}(p')\Gamma\int\frac{d^4l}{l^2}b^{(2)}(p,p)
   \frac{i}{\not{p}_1-m}\not{l}\frac{(-i)}{\not{p}_1-\not{l}-m}\not{l}\frac{i}{\not{p}_1-m}
   \not{\epsilon}^*_1u(p)$$

When adding the three contributions, I do not recover the result given by the authors, which is
$$\frac{2i\alpha}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{d^4l}{l^2}b^{(2)}(p,p) \times \bigg[\bar{u}(p')\Gamma\frac{i}{\not{p}_1-m}\not{\epsilon}^*_1u(p)\bigg]$$
Therefore, I would like someone to take a quick look and hopefully comment on the things I might be missing or any other holes in my way of thinking... Any help will be appreciated.

**P.S.#1:** I have also made use of the following identities (that are also subject to validation), but I write them down for completeness sake
$$\frac{i}{\not{p}-\not{l}-m}\not{l}\frac{i}{\not{p}-m}=\frac{i}{\not{p}-\not{l}-m}-\frac{i}{\not{p}-m}\\
\frac{i}{\not{p}+\not{l}-m}\not{l}\frac{i}{\not{p}-m}=\frac{i}{\not{p}-m}-\frac{i}{\not{p}-\not{l}-m}\\
\frac{i}{\not{p}\pm\not{l}-m}\not{l}u(p)=\pm iu(p)$$
**P.S.#2:** I can derive the desired result if I neglect completely the first term (1) and add the following contributions from (2) and (3) respectively
$$-\frac{2i\alpha}{(2\pi)^3}\bar{u}(p')\Gamma\int\frac{d^4l}{l^2}b^{(2)}(p,p)
\frac{i}{\not{p}_1-\not{l}-m}\not{\epsilon}^*_1
\frac{i}{\not{p}-\not{l}-m}\not{l}u(p)
\\
-\frac{2i\alpha}{(2\pi)^3}\bar{u}(p')\Gamma\int\frac{d^4l}{l^2}b^{(2)}(p,p)
\frac{i}{\not{p}_1-\not{l}-m}\not{l}
\frac{i}{\not{p}_1-m}\not{\epsilon}^*_1u(p)$$
but this requires tossing the remaining contributions from (2) and (3), as well as tossing the contribution from (1). The latter can be justified, as we demand our amplitudes be renormalized and hence such contributions cancle with electron self-energy counter terms. But what of the remaining contributions from (2) and (3)?